# Angular 4 tutorial

Tags: angular, typescript

My team needs to study angular 4 for our next project.
I was trying to search tutorial but with almost no success,
I have found a lot of tutorials on angular 2 but almost nothing to angular 4.
So I have asked a freelancer friend and he said he has a lot of troubles when he studied angular 4 with an angular 2 tutorial.
Even in the [official website](https://angular.io/resources), there are not complete tutorials or angular 2 tutorials.
The most I was able to find is [this tutorial](https://books.ninja-squad.com/angular).

Am I in the right direction?
Must we stick to the [official tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial)?

I'm not asking for a book, I'm just trying to understand if I'm in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Follow the official docs, they are perfectly fine. Angular 2 and 4 have small differences in terms of breaking changes.

Comment: Please read the question, I wrote pretty clearly i'm not asking for a book.

Comment: IMO they are exactly the same , just read the changelog for angular 4 to know the differences. Generally the concepts are same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand that angular 2 and angular 4 are basically the same. You can call it 'angular'. The only thing you'll need to avoid is 'angularjs' - the first iteration that has been majorly overhauled since v2 - including it's [versioning strategy](https://toddmotto.com/please-stop-worrying-about-angular-3). That's also why there's a distinction in it's name.

The documentation and resources for angular on the official [angular.io](https://angular.io/) are very detailed and up-to-date. I highly recommend just going through the [official tutourial ('Tour of Heroes')](https://angular.io/tutorial). You will learn all the basic concepts and best practices.

*As a side note:* 'angular 3' does not exist. This is due to a versioning conflict where the angular-router already jumped to version 3. To avoid confusion and sync up the versions version 4 was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Though the accepted answer correctly points that angular 4 is the next logical version of angular 2.

but if you're someone who has never done any angularjs or angular 2 , it could be an interesting idea to start straight from angular 4

Here're some interesting links to get you on your way ::

[Learn Angular 4](https://rishabh.io/misc/angular-4-tutorial.html)

[Official Heros App Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial)

[Angular Architecture](https://angular.io/guide/architecture)

Comment: -1 I have mentioned the angular links in the question, it seem you didn't read my question. And besides you answered pretty late.

Answer (score 0):

If your team already knows Angular 2 you can go with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhzGSHNhnbI/) tutorail. This tutorial will cover most of Angular 4 in just 60 minutes.
You can also follow [Quick-start guide](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart). Even if people are new to Angular they can grasp it easily here. Only fundamental programming, basic HTML is required.